# Migration problems from FQL v1.0 to Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am migrating the Facebook API that I use, from FQL v.1.0 to Graph API. I discovered that some things have deprecated. My problem is related to getting all the users that are using my application.

In FQL I can do this with:

```
/fql?q=select+uid+FROM+user+WHERE+is_app_user+AND+udi=
```

Question 1 : Table user contains all the users friends and non-friends? Or just the friends?

In Graph Api, I have understood that is_app_user is not used anymore, instead there is fields=installed that does the same thing.
I have found two ways of using fields=installed :

```
me/friends?fields=installed
```

OR

```
me/fields=installed
```

Question 2 : There is a difference between these two syntaxes?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `installed` as parameter with `/me/friends` makes no sense because

```
/me/friends
```

returns only `friends who are already using the app.`

With v2.0, Facebook has made it impossible to fetch users who are not my friends but are using the app. If you still need such users,the best solution would be to store the user-ids of all your app users in a persistent storage. A workaround using FQL should be avoided as its getting deprecated too with v2.1.